# How to format list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I am trying to format a list for this:

```
['w', 'e', '5', 'p', '4', '7', '2', 'w']
```

to this:

```
we5p472w
```

Any idea how to do this?

NOTE: this is a LIST, not a STRING

Answer (score 7):

Use the `join()` method:

```
l = ['w', 'e', '5', 'p', '4', '7', '2', 'w']

print (''.join(l))
```

Outut:

```
we5p472w
```

You can use any expression to join your list elements:

```
print (' '.join(l))
```

Output:

```
w e 5 p 4 7 2 w
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code:**

```
myList = ['w', 'e', '5', 'p', '4', '7', '2', 'w']
myString = "".join(myList)
print(myString)
```

**Output:**

```
$ we5p472w
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = ['w', 'e', '5', 'p', '4', '7', '2', 'w']
print("".join(list1))
```

returns `we5p472w`

check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/ for a more detail explanation and more examples